# What is the process of getting browser support to my custom application layer protocol?

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols, standards, network-protocols

I have a custom protocol(TCP based) working with 2 java based client and a server as a prototype. If I am to get browsers support to this what is the process and what are my chances?

Answer (score 1):

"Browser support"?

If you need a web server there are two basic approaches: you either write one yourself or you adapt one that's already available. For the latter, you can either integrate your application into the server by using a present API or write a frontend interfacing with your application (which is probably the most common approach).